How can I use sample weights with Sklearn SimpleImputer?
When imputing the na's inside of a pipeline that is fed into GridSearchCV, I would like to have each fold's na's imputed with the weighted mean. SimpleImputer can do it with the unweighted means, but I'm not sure how to do it with the weighted means.
I tried to use the same method I did with adjust StandardScalar for weights, but there are no sample_weight options. When I look at SimpleImputer().get_metadata_routing() it just returns a blank dictionary.
Here is how I got the StandardScaler to account for weights:
weighted_StandardScaler = StandardScaler().set_fit_request(sample_weight=True).set_partial_fit_request(sample_weight=True)

I need something similar for SimpleImputer such as:
weighted_SimpleImputer = SimpleImputer().set_fit_request(sample_weight=True).set_partial_fit_request(sample_weight=True)

or
weighted_SimpleImputer =
SimpleImputer(strategy='weighted_mean')

